Dynamic Header with prawn gem
I'm encountering an issue while rendering a header with the report_date argument passed into the render_header method. Despite passing a different report_date value each time, the PDF always displays the same date, which is not the expected behavior.
My expectation is that the PDF should render with the report_date value that's passed to the render_header method. However, it seems like the report_date argument isn't being utilized correctly within the method.
      def render_pages(pdf)
        grouped_items = rows.group_by { |item| item[0] }

        grouped_items.each_with_index do |(report_date, booking_items), index|
          render_page(pdf, report_date, booking_items)
          pdf.start_new_page unless index == grouped_items.size - 1
        end
      end

      # Renders a page of the PDF
      #
      # @param pdf [Prawn::Document] The PDF object
      def render_page(pdf, report_date, booking_items)
        pdf.repeat(:all, dynamic: true) do
          pdf.bounding_box([pdf.bounds.left, pdf.bounds.top], width: pdf.bounds.width) do
            render_header(pdf, report_date, organisation_name)
          end
          pdf.bounding_box([pdf.bounds.left, pdf.bounds.bottom + 150 ], width: pdf.bounds.width) do
            render_footer(pdf)
          end
        end
        render_body(pdf, report_date , booking_items)
      end

      def render_header(pdf, report_date, organisation_name)
        pdf.image open("https://s3.amazonaws.com/www-inside-design/uploads/2019/05/woolmarkimagelogo-1024x576.png"), width: 80, height: 80, position: :center
        pdf.text "HEY #{report_date}"
        pdf.table(
          [
            ["#{"Sumanth Samala PVT LTD"} - #{format_report_date(report_date)} \n Attendance Register", "Customer to complete all sections below \n Generated on #{Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")}"]
          ],
          width: pdf.bounds.width,
          row_colors: ["808080"],
          cell_style: header_cell_style
        ) do |table|
          table.column(0).width = 464
        end
      end
    ```


"unfortunately, I see the same date in all the pages" – I don't quite understand what's wrong about that. Is the date supposed to change from page to page?

I do not see anything in this code that suggests the date should change? It shows repeat(:all) which means do the same thing on every page? Your is executed using the report_date passed to render_page.   Maybe this repeater should be located somewhere else in your code?

BTW, the repeat helper is supposed to be called once for the whole document. Invoking it on every render_page call doesn't seem right and might lead to unexpected results.

Sorry all, I have updated the question with more context and some meaningfulness

In this scenario, the rows variable represents arrays of arrays derived from an external SQL query, alongside the so-called report_date. Within the render_pages function, I'm attempting to group the data based on the report_date, as follows: rows.group_by { |item| item[0] }.

Does it work when you remove the repeat wrapper and call render_header and render_footer directly?

I tried @Stefan but it didn't, I just see body wrapped by header and footer but not repeating headers and footer if you know what i mean.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

If each "report" only takes up 1 page then repeat is not necessary. If each "report" may take up more than 1 page you can pass a range or array of pages to repeat e.g. repeat((1..3)) this will likely require you to perform some calculations in your loop

thanks, @engineersmnky but how do I know if the page is taking up more than 1 page ? here is it just by watching pdf.page_number? :thinking:

Here is a stab in the dark but too long for a comment.
We can render all the pages, while keeping track of the starting page and ending page for each report date.
Then we can use repeat with those ranges to generate the header.
def render_pages(pdf)
  grouped_items = rows.group_by(&:first)

  page_breaks = grouped_items.map.with_index(1) do |(report_date, booking_items), index|
    start_page = pdf.page_number
    render_page(pdf, report_date, booking_items)
    end_page = pdf.page_number 
    pdf.start_new_page unless index == grouped_items.size
    {pages: (start_page..end_page), report_date: report_date}
  end
  render_header_footer(pdf,page_breaks)
end

def render_page(pdf, report_date, booking_items)
  render_body(pdf, report_date , booking_items)
end

def render_header_footer(pdf,pages_headers)
  pages_headers.each do |page_data|
    pdf.repeat(page_data[:pages], dynamic: true) do
      pdf.bounding_box([pdf.bounds.left, pdf.bounds.top], width: pdf.bounds.width) do
        render_header(pdf, page_data[:report_date], organisation_name)
      end
      pdf.bounding_box([pdf.bounds.left, pdf.bounds.bottom + 150 ], width: pdf.bounds.width) do
        render_footer(pdf)
      end
    end
  end
end 

def render_header(pdf, report_date, organisation_name)
  pdf.image open("https://s3.amazonaws.com/www-inside-design/uploads/2019/05/woolmarkimagelogo-1024x576.png"), width: 80, height: 80, position: :center
  pdf.text "HEY #{report_date}"
  pdf.table(
    [
      ["#{"Sumanth Samala PVT LTD"} - #{format_report_date(report_date)} \n Attendance Register", "Customer to complete all sections below \n Generated on #{Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")}"]
    ],
    width: pdf.bounds.width,
    row_colors: ["808080"],
    cell_style: header_cell_style
  ) do |table|
    table.column(0).width = 464
  end
end


Wow, that worked like a charm mate. @engineersmnky saved my day. Thank you so so much. appreciate it.
